# Comparing two strings containing a set of numbers regardless of their order in Java

Tags: java, string, numbers, sequence

I need to compare two sets of numbers in Java.  For the sake of testing the program the two sets will be the same (123) except one set will have "123" in different orders.  I am currently inputing "123" as the winning number and "321" as the playing number using the .contains() method to compare the two as Strings.

My code is as follows:

```
    if (playNum.contains(winNum))
        System.out.println("True") ;
    else
        System.out.println("False") ;
```

Im trying to get the program to recognize any variation of '123' as a winner. Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: Sort the two `String`s...

Comment: I am not at all clear on what you're looking for.  Are you comparing two sets, or testing to see if one value is an element of the set?  Are you working with strings or numbers?  What's the declaration of `playNum` and `winNum`?  How is `playNum` built?  What do you mean by "variation"?

Comment: @ajb Sorry for not being clear. The two "numbers" are actually Strings. I need for a way to have the program to output 'True' when playNum contains any of the characters winNum contains. For example if winNum is '123' then i would need a 'True' out when playNum is '123','132','213','321','312' etc.

Comment: A combination of `String.split(regex)`, `Integer.valueOf(string)` and `Collection.contains(object)` is what I would probably do. Would that method work for you?

Comment: Is it `true` or `false` if `playNum="1234"` and `winNum="432"`?

Comment: Here are some questions concerning bounds. Is it possible that winNum can be "000000"? What will happen in such case? Will it always be split into single digit numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look on my solution and let me know if this is what you want:

```
    String input = "123";
    String winner = "321";
    char[] inputArr = input.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(inputArr);

    char[] winnerArr = winner.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(winnerArr);

    boolean retval = Arrays.equals(inputArr, winnerArr);
    System.out.println(retval);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a little hint code snippet to help you figure out your problem.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*[^1-3].*");

   String [] inputs = {"123", "-123" , "123.12", "abcd123"};

   for(String input: inputs){
       System.out.println( "does " + input + " is number : "
                            + !pattern.matcher(input).matches());
   }

   // Regular expression in java to check if String is 6 digit number or not
   String [] numbers = {"123", "123" };
   Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}");
```